# CSS border-image with fixed center

Tags: html, css, border-image

I want to use something like the below image for div border:
[image]

I do not want to center be stretched (for wide and high div). How should I slice this photo that the center remains fixed?

```
border-style: solid;
border-width: 41px 23px 46px 21px;
-moz-border-image: url(6.png) 41 23 46 21 stretch repeat;
-webkit-border-image: url(6.png) 41 23 46 21 stretch repeat;
-o-border-image: url(6.png) 41 23 46 21 stretch repeat;
border-image: url(6.png) 41 23 46 21 fill stretch repeat;
```

Comment: will the background of the div and the surrounding elements always be white?

Comment: No, the background is changeable. @haxxxton

Comment: @haxxxton Can you tell me a part from white color what all colors u want in background?

Comment: @sanjay, that's a question for the OP, the curved fill area is going to be damn near impossible to do..

Comment: @NaserYousefi, can you supply a link to a `svg` of the above image please

Comment: @haxxxton My bad! My last question was for NaserYousefi.

Comment: I've removed the css-shapes tag because this is ***not*** a shapes question. It is a question about border image.

Comment: I've added css-shapes and border-image tags as well because OP is looking for solution only in one particular domain while some other possible areas could offer much better solutions.

Comment: the CSS-Shapes tag is used for shapes made using pure CSS. This is not a shape that would be feasible with CSS and as such would not be classed as css-shapes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Cut the top central part of the above image and draw using `background-image`.
2. Draw the left/right parts with `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements.

**Output Image:**

[image: Output Image]

```css
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
body {
  background: linear-gradient(purple, white) no-repeat;
  min-height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}
.box {
  background-image: url("https://s30.postimg.org/r1e86dtr5/border_image.png"), url("https://s30.postimg.org/r1e86dtr5/border_image.png");

  background-size: 288px 39px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center top, center bottom;

  padding: 40px 20px;
  position: relative;
  min-width: 300px;
  height: 250px;
  width: 500px;
  margin: 20px;
}
.box:before,
.box:after {
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 2px 0 2px 2px;
  width: calc(50% - 142px);
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  bottom: 17px;
  top: 19px;
  left: 0;
}
.box:after {
  border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
  border-width: 2px 2px 2px 0;
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Comment: Possibly worth mentioning that this only works if the `.box` element is transparent, any `background-color` will break the design. To make the box responsively width'ed use `width:calc(50% - 142px);` on the `:before` and `:after` style definitions

Comment: Thank you, muhammad-usman. I think @haxxxton suggestion properly completed your answer. please add width:calc(50% - 142px) to your solution to complete it.
Thank you haxxxton.

Comment: @haxxxton I've added necessary adjustments. Thank You)